# given GCM sender ID, determine Google account

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) 
"sender ID".  (This is the "project number" 
of a project in the Google Cloud Console.)
I want to generate a GCM API key, as described at
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#access-key.
But to do that, I need to know what Google account was
used to create the GCM sender ID, information I don't
currently have.  Is there any way to get that information?

I would be happy to pay Google for this
information, but I don't see any way of doing
so.  Google Cloud Platform Support (described at
https://cloud.google.com/support/packages) doesn't seem
to be helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The GCM sender ID described in the  [Creating a Google API project](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#access-key) is same as your  project number.What problems you have for creation of API key

After selecting your project from [Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/console)Just click the Registerd apps  and just click your project. It will show your API Key

Comment: I can't select my project in the Cloud Console,
because I can't log into the account, because
I don't know what the account is.  This should
be clear from the post above (at least, I hope
it is).

Comment: @PotatoRepublic In that case you can create a new account and get a new sender ID and API key.

Comment: Eran: I'm afraid not -- the app has already been deployed.  Customers already have it on their phones.

Comment: You can give an updation of your project after using GCM. Create a new account and you can create new project. In server side you have to keep the sender Id. Should care your database when changing